# How to determine the maximum number of messages in *USRQ

Tags: ibm-midrange

It is required to create *USRQ of the largest possible size.
According to the documentation, the maximum size for *USRQ is 2Gb.
Creating a queue requires specifying the maximum message size, the initial number of messages in the queue, the size (in messages) of the queue expansion, and the maximum number of expansion operations.
Let's the message size is 1024 bytes. The initial number is 128 messages. The queue will expand by 128 messages.
Estimate the maximum possible number of messages - 2Gb / 128 bytes. Then we subtract the initial number of messages (128) and divide by the size of the extension - 128. As a result, we get the maximum number of extensions - 16,383.
We pass these parameters to QUSCRTUQ, after which we look at what we got (call matqat).
We see that the maximum number of extensions (mat_template.Max_Extend) is set less than the requested one - 15 306, and the maximum number of messages in the queue is therefore is 1 959 296
Then start filling the queue and at some point get the error "Tried to go larger than storage limit" At the same time, the number of messages in the queue is 1,957,504, the number of extensions used is 15,282.
Why does this happen and how to correctly estimate the maximum number of increments when creating a queue?

Comment: Whomever voted to close this because they think it is a networking question, doesn't have a clue. It is like voting to close a Java question about hash table sizes because it isn't about programming. A *USRQ is a low level object type on the IBM i OS, accessible only to programmers via a specific API. Trying to get information about how it uses memory is specifically a programming question.

Comment: I think you have a valid question, and I hope someone has an answer for you. But I don't know anything about user queues (I hadn't heard of them until I saw this question), so I can't answer. But I'm commenting because I wonder: does your user queue behave as you would expect for a small number of messages? And do you really need the absolute maximum? What kind of application *needs* to be able to enqueue 1.9 million messages, and falls apart if it can only enqueue 1.8 million?

Comment: In our case, queues (*DTAQ and *USRQ) are used where parallel processing of large amounts of data is required. By large volumes, we understand 20-40 million records. Which are processed in parallel in several threads.
From the point of view of maintainability, it is more convenient to use not threads, but separate jobs.
Thus, there is a head job that creates a queue and starts the required number of worker jobs. Next, the head job takes care of selecting data for processing and placing it in a queue from where the data is taken by workers and processed.

Comment: *DTAQ provides more features (remote queues, journaling...) but they are not important for us. *USRQ, in turn, is about 4 times faster and, which is very important for us, requires about 4 times less CPU resources (according to the results of PEX statistics).
In addition, with large volumes of the queue, *DTAQ begins to be saved to disk, which leads to a noticeable slowdown in its operation. *USRQ doesn't have this - it's always fast.

Comment: Naturally, we control the degree of filling the queue, but for this we need to know exactly the maximum number of messages that it can accommodate. The question is related to this - how to correctly calculate the maximum queue size. The system itself does this incorrectly. Or am I doing something wrong and I don’t understand something (which is most likely)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, but none of that convinces me that you will be *that* worse off by simply pretending that the absolute maximum size is, say, 1.8 GB. Or do some further experimentation to find out a "safe" number that gives you confidence that the system can deliver what you ask of it.

Comment: The problem is that I don't understand how it works. And this "maximum number" is not constant.
The QUSCRTUQ API has (among others) 4 parameters: Maximum message size, Initial number of messages, Additional number of messages, and Number of queue extensions. The first three are set by the user, the last is calculated based on the maximum size for the queue - 2GB.
The same parameters can be viewed for an existing queue by calling MI MATQAT.

Comment: The situation is very dependent on the value of the first three parameters. Suppose the Maximum Message Size = 128, Initial Number of Messages = 128 and the Aditional Number of Messages = 128. I calculate the Number of Queue Extensions and call Quscrtuq. The line is created correctly. Then I call Matqat and see that the Number of Queue Extensions there are less than I handed over. Those. The system itself calculated something there and calculated the real value of the parameter Number of Queue Extensions.

Comment: But the trouble is that when I begin to fill out the queue, at some point there is a mistake of its overflow. Those. The Number of Queue Extensions parameter is defined incorrectly by the system. But that is not all. If I increase the Maximum Message Size parameter to 16kb, then everything will work correctly. It can also work correctly with some other combinations of parameters.

Comment: A purely intuitive assumption: this is the very moment when the system does not have enough memory to store the contents of the queue, and in the case of *DTAQ, the queue is flushed to disk and slowed down. And since *USRQ is not flushed to disk (an *USRQ type object stores only the description of the queue, but not its contents), the exception 1C04 Object Storage Limit Exceeded (MCH2804) is simply thrown.

Comment: And another moment. The physical size of the message in the queue is equal to the declared message size (Maximum message size parameter) + key size (for FIFO / LIFO queues it is 0) + 16 bytes of message attributes (Message enqueue time - Char(8) + Message length - Bin(4) + Reserved - Char(4))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with more experimentation you will find that IBM i always allocates memory in pages. It is probably going through the allocation procedure for each message and allocating space on the *USRQ from the previous memory allocation until the allocated memory is full, then it allocates another block large enough to contain the next allocation.

Let me give you a simple example. A dataarea can be up to 2000 bytes, but no matter what size you make it, it always shows a physical size of 8K bytes. Internally, it knows how much of that 8K space can be used.

So what is happening?

- You create a *USRQ with a minimal size: 1 message 64 bytes/message.
- The system creates an object with a minimal physical size 16K but a smaller logical size 64bytes + overhead
- You add a message
- The system adds a message
- You add another message
- The system checks to see if it has enough memory allocated for the next message and if so extends the logical size of the *USRQ.
- The system then adds the message
- This continues as messages are added until the allocated memory is no longer large enough to hold the next extension. At this point the OS allocates more physical memory in page increments, but at least enough to hold the requested extension.

So there are a couple allocation schemes going on here. The *USRQ routines are extending the logical size of the object based on the *USRQ parameters, and the OS is allocating physical memory in page size blocks as requested by the *USRQ routines. Thus a *USRQ extension does not necessarily require a physical memory allocation. It also points out a possible optimization based on setting the initial size of the queue such that it fills up at least 16K, and also setting the size of the extension such that it fills up at least 4K. That way the API is not running through the extension logic more often than necessary.

Comment: The potential optimization is an interesting idea. I take it by "at least" you mean "an exact multiple of the page size, with the initial queue size being at least 4 pages"?

Comment: As far as I know, any memory manager on any system allocates memory not by bytes, but by pages.
In this case, the question was not how exactly the memory is allocated (here I just saw with my own eyes those details that are not described in the documentation).
The main problem was how to correctly determine the physical size of the message (knowing the size of the message requested by the user) to determine the maximum possible number of queue expansions.

Comment: This problem is a consequence of the fact that the system itself is not able to do this. A simple example that I stumbled upon and that was actually the reason for this research.
Suppose, when creating a queue, I specify the maximum number of extensions 1,000,000 (all figures are conditional) - this is a deliberately overestimated value, taking into account the remaining parameters (message size, initial number of messages, number of messages per extension).

Comment: The system "sees" that with this set of parameters the maximum queue size will exceed the possible limit of 2GB and sets its own value for the maximum number of extensions, which I can see after creating the queue using MATQAT. There I see that the maximum number of extensions is set not as requested 1,000,000, but only 500,000 (again, conditional)

Comment: But the trouble is that this value is too high. If I count the maximum number of messages based on the data returned by MATQAT (initial number of messages + maximum number of extensions * number of messages per extension), and then try to queue the received number of messages, I will get the exception "Tried to go larger than storage limit".

Comment: Thus, the goal of the study was to learn how to correctly determine the maximum number of queue extensions, for which it was necessary to estimate how much the physical size of the message in the queue is greater than the message size specified by the user. And the subtleties of memory allocation are just a by-product of the proposed approach using DMPOBJ.

Comment: The mechanism for changing the queue size itself was not a surprise - this is quite expected. I just made sure that the initial physical size of the queue matches the size of the associated space, and the increment of the physical size matches the size of the page (both values for a particular machine can be obtained via MATMDATA), although these specific values are not important for calculations, it is only important that the size message requested by the user, you need to add 16 bytes to the header and 64 bytes to the internal service information.

Comment: One more little wrinkle which makes it hard to determine the exact lengths. The messages put on the queue are variable length. That is why they ask for max length of the message. So the actual number of messages the queue can hold depends on the actual length of the messages. If it is always the same, and you can determine the length of the overhead (queue overhead, message overhead, and key overhead if you have a keyed queue), then you should be able to determine the exact number of messages the queue can hold. One more thing to consider is alignment.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that there is (and must be) some internal "overhead" for a queue to keep all of the enqueued messages chained together in the proper LIFO or FIFO order, etc.   These internal "linked lists" or "pointers" are not "free".

Create a small test *USRQ, and then do a DMPOBJ of that.  Then add a few messages to the queue, and DMPOBJ of that again.  Then "de-queue" a few messages, and do another DMPOBJ.   Then compare the spool files of these dumps to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. I will definitely try.

Comment: Mark, thank you very much. And your ideas helped. Details are in the comments below.
In general, I estimate the hidden data at 64 bytes. Plus another 16 bytes for the message header. A total of 80 bytes in addition to the message size declared by the user.
If we consider the maximum number of messages, taking into account the above, everything works correctly.

Comment: In more detail, then this: the size of the message is 64 bytes. The initial number of messages is 1. The size of the increment is 1 message. With these parameters, the initial queue size is 16Kb. Further, as messages are added up to the 26th message, the size of the queue does not change. When adding the 27th - increases by 4Kb (page size reported by MATMDATA). Further, the queue size does not change until the 55th message. When adding the 56th, it again increases by 4Kb. The next increase is after 86 messages when adding the 87th.

Comment: Now it is approximately clear how USRQ works and how to manage it.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer your question directly, but I don't think my comments are working, so I'll try an answer.

The [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=ssw_ibm_i_73/apis/quscrtuq.htm) says

> If the number of queue extensions is specified and non-zero, the queue will be extended by the number of additional messages specified until either the number of queue extensions is reached or the storage limit of 2GB is reached.

In other words, the number of extensions you specify in QUSCRTUQ is just a request; the system will stop you before you reach that number if the limit would be exceeded.

As pointed out in [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72217141/95852), there is going to be overhead which uses up some of that 2GB, so it shouldn't be surprising that MATQAT reports a number of extensions lower than what you requested.

What *is* surprising (to me, anyway) is that when you actually add data to the queue, you might not even get the number of extensions reported by MATQAT. So the only way to get an accurate number seems to be adding data until you get the error message.

Given that, the next thing I would look at is what the possible user inputs are. Can they enter literally anything? Or do they have to choose among a limited set of values? If the number of possible combinations of user input is "manageable" then you could write a script which tries all of them. Use a huge value for the number of extensions (deliberately requesting more than 2GB) and monitor for the error message to capture the number of extensions you really got. If you can do this for every possible user input, then you can make a lookup table for the number of extensions, and actually use it instead of doing arithmetic.

If there are too many possible user inputs, then you just have to try a representative sample. And instead of a lookup table, do arithmetic, but based on the smallest effective size encountered in the sample (or even smaller, to provide a margin of safety).

Comment: In fact, everything is simpler and more difficult at the same time.
The matter is that the reliable tool of control over queue is required to me. Quite optionally (and almost certainly not) I will fill the queue at 100%. But I want to be 100% sure that the number of messages I received from MATQAT will fit into the queue without error.
Apparently, the system itself erroneously determines the number of queue expansions in the case when I passed it a deliberately overestimated value. So there is only one way out - to learn to determine the correct value yourself.

Comment: @MarkSWaterbury gave good advice in his answer. I ran a series of tests and saw this: When the queue is created, its size is 16Kb (0x4000). Further, the size increment occurs by one page (4Kb, 0x1000, the exact page size can be obtained using MATMDATA) regardless of the message size and the number of messages in one increment (I used a message size of 64 bytes, the increment size is 1 message, but the physical size of the queue still changed not when adding each message, but periodically and immediately on the page size).

Comment: Therefore, it was difficult to understand exactly how much space in the queue a single message actually takes (including hidden data). I estimated the size as User defined message size + 16 bytes of header (8 bytes of time, 4 bytes of length and 4 more spare bytes) + 64 bytes of some internal data. Total 80 bytes over custom message size.
Then, if we assume that 2GB / (MessageSize + 80) can be placed in the queue, subtract the initial number of messages from this and divide by the size of the increment, then we get the maximum possible number of increments. And this approach works correctly.

Comment: Those. the whole question was in determining the correct physical size of memory per message to determine the correct maximum number of messages in the queue. Those same 64 bytes of hidden data played a role.

Comment: Congratulations on figuring it out! Now maybe you should post your own answer (you can self-answer questions here) so that the information is properly presented for other people who are searching for how user queue storage is allocated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I want to say thanks to everyone who commented and answered - it helped a lot to find a solution.
Special thanks to @MarkSWaterbury - your answer was very helpful in finding the right approach in finding a solution.
What we managed to understand and see.

The following parameters were chosen for the experiment:

- the size of one message is 64 bytes
- initial queue capacity - 1 message
- queue increment - 1 message

That. each time a new message is added, the size of the queue should increase.

After the queue is created, its size is 16Kb. This is the same as the size of the "associated space" (which can be obtained via MATMDATA).

Regardless of the size of the message and the size of the queue increment (the number of messages in the increment), the physical size of the queue does not increase every time, but due to lack of capacity and a multiple of 1 page (MATMDATA says that the page size is 4Kb).

In our case, the first 26 messages do not cause a change in the physical size of the queue. The 27th leads to its increase by 4Kb. Further, until the 55th message, the physical size of the queue does not change. The 56th increases it by another 4Kb. Then up to the 86th without changes, the 87th again increases the physical size by 4Kb...

All this allows us to evaluate the alleged Mark S Waterbury "internal overhead".
Here, also, it should be noted that the physical size of the message in the queue consists of the user-specified maximum message size and the size of the message header - Message attributes in a structure filled with MATQMSG and containing:

- Message enqueue time Char(8)
- Message length Bin(4)
- Reserved Char(4)

For a KEYED queue, the key size is added to the physical size of the message.

Using the proposed method, we can roughly estimate the "internal overhead" mentioned above, which is 64 bytes (perhaps a little less, because due to the page increment of the physical size of the queue, the exact value is different each time, but with alignment by 16 let it be like this).

In total, we get an additional 80 bytes to the sum of the maximum message size specified by the user and the key size (for KEYED queues, for FIFO and LIFO queues, the key size is 0).

Now, if we count the maximum number of increments, based on the specified maximum queue size (2GB, as indicated in the documentation) and the physical size of the message, defined as described above, we get the correct value, which we pass to QUSCRTUQ. If we then call MATQAT and calculate back the maximum size of messages in the queue, using the values returned to it Initial number of messages, Additional number of messages and Number of queue extensions, we get the real value of the maximum number of messages in the queue, which does not throw exception 1C04 "Object Storage Limit Exceeded" (MCH2804).
That. now you can control the degree of filling the queue by the ratio of the number of messages in it and the calculated maximum number of messages without fear of an exception.

And what is all this for? If we have *DTAQ with which everything is much simpler...
The thing is, if we don't need all the features of *DTAQ (journaling, saving content to disk, using remote queues...) and we only work with local queues, *USRQ is 4-5 times faster and consumes about the same times less CPU resources.